# Flask add parameter to view methods in before_request

Tags: python, flask

Lets say I have an API at /api/something. The API requires a definition for api_key, it looks in the request arguments and the cookies. If it finds the api_key, I want it to pass the api_key to the route methods, in this case `something`.

```
@app.before_request
def pass_api_key():
    api_key = request.args.get('api_key', None)
    if api_key is None:
        api_key = request.cookies.get('api_key', None)
    if api_key is None:
        return 'api_key is required'
    # add parameter of api_key to something method

@app.route('/api/something')
def something(api_key):
    return api_key
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use `flask.g`. From [the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#application-globals):

> To share data that is valid for one request only from one function to another, a global variable is not good enough because it would break in threaded environments. Flask provides you with a special object that ensures it is only valid for the active request and that will return different values for each request.

Set `g.api_key` to the value you want to store in `before_request` and read it out in the route method.

`flask.g`, like `flask.request`, is what Flask and Werkzeug call a ["context local"](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/local/) object - roughly, an object that pretends to be global, but really exposes different values to each request.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using the `url_value_processor` decorator:

```
@app.url_value_preprocessor
def get_project_object(endpoint, values):
    api_key = values.get('api_key')
    if api_key is None:
        api_key = request.cookies.get('api_key', None)
    if api_key is None:
        raise Exception('api_key is required')
    values['api_key'] = api_key
```

This can also be done in a Blueprint basis, so that it only applies to the views in the specified Blueprint.